# Java program does not work well with JFilechooser

Tags: java, jfilechooser

I have a java program and I use JFilechooser to search and  load a file from my computer.But what I see a java's kind of file chooser window popping up but not the operating system kind of file chooser window like when we try to save a file ,save as or like ...How do I make opering systems kinda file chooser window pop up to search for files ???

Comment: Please add you code.. we cant tell you what is wrong on this information.

Comment: nothing is wrong ..a File chooser window pops up but It's a java kinda filechooser..But it is not the window operating system 7's usual filechooser that pops up when we try to save a file ,or upload a file to web

Comment: for that you can use  UIManager.setLookAndFeel.

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Metal".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
    }
```